# Which encryption method does Prestashop use for the password field and how does it do it?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Which encryption method does Prestashop use for the password field and how does it do it?
I want to encrypt the password field using the same technique as Prestashop.
Currently I am using this one:

```
$pass=md5($password);
```

Comment: a) md5 is a **hash**, not an encryption. b) md5 has been a **insecure** hash for over a decade. **don't** use it. c) PHP provides `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for all your password hashing needs. **use them** whenever possible d) if you want to know what prestashop uses, you should ask prestashop - not us.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I agree, however prestashop still uses md5.

Comment: @TheDrot that's why i added "whenever possible". this would, however, rather be a reason to not use prestashop, or write a patch so it uses secure functions.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann This is a fair question, for example if you want to make your own API to develop an external application where users can log in with their shop account: you need to know which encryption method uses Prestashop in order to use it when saving and checking if user's password is right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`Tools.php`](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/master/classes/Tools.php)

[line `1180` (version 1.6.1.x)](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Tools.php#L1180)

```
public static function encrypt($passwd)
{
    return md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd);
}
```

[line `1069` (version 1.7)](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.0.x/classes/Tools.php#L1069)

```
public static function hash($passwd)
{
    return md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd);
}
```

In 1.6 `_COOKIE_KEY_` is defined in `/config/settings.inc.php`

In 1.7 it's defined in [/config/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.0.x/config/bootstrap.php#L112)

Comment: Where did you get line 1178? I see lines 1055 and 1069 on their [Github](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Tools.php) page.

Comment: @mistermartin That's prestashop 1.7 version.

Comment: On 1.7, its not defined in settings.inc.php. I can't find where it's coming from though

Comment: @VeeK it's defined in /config/bootstrap.php.

Comment: Prestashop doesn't use MD5 anymore, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895336/prestashop-1-7-customer-password-encryption
It uses 12-round bcrypt now

Answer (score 6):

In 1.6 `_COOKIE_KEY_` is defined in `/config/settings.inc.php`

In 1.7 it is generated from this file `/config/bootstrap.php` but stored here `/app/config/parameters.php`

If you are trying to insert directly in database than select md5 first than paste `_COOKIE_KEY_` and type password.

Answer (score 1):

After doing what Vividus says, you have to execute this query in **phpmyadmin**:

```
    UPDATE ps_employee SET passwd=md5("COOKIE_KEY+Your_new_pass") 
WHERE email="email_user
```

The "plus" sign does not go inside the quotes, it's all together `COOKIE_KEY` and your new password.