# Prestashop 1.7 Customer Password Encryption?

Tags: php, prestashop, bcrypt, prestashop-1.7, password-hash

I made some third party system based with php for Prestashop 1.6. It works with connecting directly the Prestashop Database. And know Im upgraded my Presta to 1.7.5.1 and IT WORKS. Only It dont log in customers anymore because as I can see Password encryption is changed. I was using md5(COOKIE_KEY.'password') for 1.6, but I see the passwords on 1.7 nothing like md5. Could you tell me how encryption is. (it become much better if you tell me with php code)

Prestashop 1.7.5.1

$2y$10$6b460aRLklgWblz75NAMteYXLJwjfV6a/uN8GJKgJgPDBuNhHs.ym

for 123456

Answer (score 3):

**PrestaShop 1.7.x now uses [bcrypt](https://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) as the preferred hash method (md5 is still supported though).**

To better understand the behavior between PrestaShop v1.6.x vs 1.7.x for checking passwords, let's have a look at the `getByEmail()` method in the Customer class:

```
/**
  * Return customer instance from its e-mail (optionally check password).
  *
  * @param string $email e-mail
  * @param string $plaintextPassword Password is also checked if specified
  * @param bool $ignoreGuest
  *
  * @return bool|Customer|CustomerCore Customer instance
 */
 public function getByEmail($email, $plaintextPassword = null, $ignoreGuest = true)
```

If `$plaintextPassword` is provided the encrypted version of the password is retrieved with:

```
$this->passwd = $crypto->hash($plaintextPassword);
```

The Hashing class can be instancied by doing:

```
$crypto = ServiceLocator::get('\\PrestaShop\\PrestaShop\\Core\\Crypto\\Hashing');
```

**Solution for your example using PrestaShop 1.7 classes/methods:**

```
<?php

namespace PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Crypto;
include('config/config.inc.php');

$plaintextPassword = '123456';
$crypto = new Hashing;
$encryptedPassword = $crypto->hash($plaintextPassword, _COOKIE_KEY_);

echo 'Clear: '.$plaintextPassword.'<br />Encrypted: '.$encryptedPassword;

/* Result (example)
Clear: 123456
Encrypted: $2y$10$6b460aRLklgWblz75NAMteYXLJwjfV6a/uN8GJKgJgPDBuNhHs.ym */
```

**Alternate solution, without the need to include any PrestaShop files/methods:**

```
<?php

$plaintextPassword = '123456';
$encryptedPassword = password_hash($plaintextPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo var_dump(password_verify($plaintextPassword, $encryptedPassword)); // True if encryption is matching
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to include any prestashop file. So how is md5 supported like before "(md5 is still supported though)" Can I use old type of encryption or can I encrypt just like this without including any prestashop file?

Comment: @AnılTürk, I would strongly advise against using md5 as the encryption level is now considered too weak. I edited my answer to provide an alternate solution using bcrypt and without the need to include any PrestaShop files nor the cookie key. I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I tried that but it always return true.Also I tried including the config file solution. It redirects the shop homepage.

Comment: Solution 2 returns always true also if plaintextPassword is wrong. Any idea?