# How to make login in Flutter and Prestashop

Tags: rest, flutter, web-services, authentication, prestashop-1.7

I use Prestashop Web Service in my flutter project , I can get and post data and  register the customer but i faced a problem in login.
the login in Prestashop required to hash the password for verifying.
I tried many packages for hashing like [crypto package](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) , but nothing worked.
and this is my code.

// get user info function to get password

```
Future<List<Info>> getUserInfo(String email) async {
var url =
    'https://www.example.com/api/customers?filter[email]=$email&display=[id,lastname,firstname,passwd]';

List<Info> data = new List();
Response response;

response = await get(url, headers: <String, String>{
  'authorization': getAuth(),
});

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  if (response.body.length != 0) {
    var raw = XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
    var elements = raw.findAllElements("customer");

    data.addAll(elements.map((element) {
      return Info(
        customerID: removeAllHtmlTags(
            element.findElements('id').single.text.toString()),
        firstName: removeAllHtmlTags(
            element.findElements('lastname').single.text.toString()),
        lastName: removeAllHtmlTags(
            element.findElements('firstname').single.text.toString()),
        password: removeAllHtmlTags(
            element.findElements('passwd').single.text.toString()),
      );
    }).toList());
  } else {
    data = null;
  }
}
return data;}
```

////Verify login

```
 Future<String> VerifyLogin({String password, String email}) async {
String result = '';
List<Info> data = await getUserInfo(email);
const cookie_key = '$cookie_key';

final cryptPass = crypto.md5
    .convert(utf8.encode(cookie_key + password))
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase();

if (data != null) {
  print(cryptPass);
  print(data.first.password);
  if (data.first.password == cryptPass) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setString('id', data.first.customerID);

    result = 'success';
  } else {
    result = 'wrong password';
  }
} else {
  result = 'wrong email';
}
return result;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop 1.7 bcrypt is being used.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895336/prestashop-1-7-customer-password-encryption) answer, it explains perfectly how Prestashop handle password encrypting / hashing.

Comment: I saw this answer but the problem i didn't find a package for encrypt password in CRYPT_BLOWFISH algoirthm, check out this documentation [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)